# State vectors of "interesting" multiple stars

Tags: orbit, binary-star, orbital-elements

I'd like to show a demonstration of Runge Kutta integration of real systems using examples of interesting multiple stars, where "interesting" means you can see through a small telescope that they are at least double. I've selected three:

1. Gamma Andromedae (Almach)
2. Alpha Geminorum (Castor)
3. Zeta Ursae Majoris (Mizar and Alcor)

How can I find a state vector (set of relative positions and velocities) - or something similar - for these multiple star systems? An open access link (for everyone) would be great, but a journal reference is fine as well if that's what it takes.

Of course the periods are long and there will be uncertainty - I'd just like to use whatever is known and available, for this demonstration.

Comment: http://simbad.u-strasbg.fr/simbad/sim-id?Ident=Gamma+Andromedae&NbIdent=1&Radius=2&Radius.unit=arcmin&submit=submit+id   http://simbad.u-strasbg.fr/simbad/sim-id?Ident=Alpha+Geminorum&NbIdent=1&Radius=2&Radius.unit=arcmin&submit=submit+id http://simbad.u-strasbg.fr/simbad/sim-id?Ident=Zeta+Ursae+Majoris+&NbIdent=1&Radius=2&Radius.unit=arcmin&submit=submit+id and follow-up the measurements and references.

Comment: Thanks @RobJeffries, honestly if I could decode those pages, I'd be smart enough to have known where to find them in the first place! I'm looking for an answer that shows me how to find *relative positions and velocities*, as will other stackexchange users in the future who find this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The USNO Sixth Catalog of Orbits of Visual Binary Stars ([ORB6](http://www.usno.navy.mil/USNO/astrometry/optical-IR-prod/wds/orb6))
has the orbital elements you need.

1. $\gamma$ And is WDS 02039+4220
2. $\alpha$ Gem is WDS 07346+3153
3. $\zeta$ UMa is WDS 13239+5456

Double star expert Bruce MacEvoy [explains](http://www.handprint.com/ASTRO/bineye3.html) orbital elements in maybe enough detail to help you work out some state vectors.
My search also turned up a [book chapter](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4614-3945-5_7) by Andreas Alzner.

Comment: This is great! Thank you for finding both the information and places where I can read to actually *understand and use* the information! I've tried the CTIO [Multiple Star Catallog](http://www.ctio.noao.edu/~atokovin/stars/) as well as the [simbad](http://simbad.u-strasbg.fr/simbad/) portal linked in the comments below the question, but couldn't understand how to use what's there.